# Find the volume of the solid that remains after a circular hole of radius a is bored through the center of a solid sphere of radius r > a.

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the volume of the solid that remains after a circular hole of radius a is bored through the center of a solid sphere of radius r > a. So in the picture it looks like a circle with a cylinder cut out of the middle. I am not even sure where to start with this. I know this has to do with integrals but I am not sure how to set this up to even get an integral. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What answer did you get?

Answer (score 0):

We can decompose the sphere as as a stack of discs with a hole in the middle:
$$
dV(z) = A(z)\, dz
$$
where the height $z$ over a full sphere with center at the origin of the coordinate system would range from $-r$ to $r$.

The radius $R(z)$ of a disc at height $z$ is
$$
R(z) = \sqrt{r^2 - z^2}
$$
The area of a solid disc is
$$
A(z) = \pi R(z)^2
$$
From this we subtract the citcular area of the hole and get:
$$
V = \int\limits_{-h}^h \pi \left(\left(r^2 - z^2\right) - a^2\right) dz
$$
The above equation features a height parameter $h \le r$. We should choose it such that the disc is not smaller than its hole. 
$$
0 = r^2 - h^2 - a^2 \iff h = \sqrt{r^2 - a^2}
$$
This gives
$$
V =  \pi\int\limits_{-\sqrt{r^2-a^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-a^2}}
\left(
r^2-a^2 - z^2
\right)
dz
$$
This 1D integral should be easy to solve. For $a=0$ the volume of a sphere with radius $r$ should result.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set this up is to take the region under the semicircle $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ for $a\le x\le r$ and revolve this around the y-axis to get the top half of the solid.

Using the shell method (and symmetry),

this gives $\displaystyle V=2\int_a^r2\pi x\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\;dx$.